# Async function in another file is not being hit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Currently, I'm trying to create a login and for some reason my code for my login is not being triggered. The function loginUserWithEmail is not being triggered.
It is not being triggered because none of the console.log's inside the loginUserWithEmail function is printed in the console.
The onSubmit() function in Login.tsx is triggers when I click a "Login" button.

Thank you.

Login.tsx:

```
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import { loginUserWithEmail, LoginFormData } from '../../actions/authActions'

const Login = ({ auth, history, login }: {auth: any, history: RouteComponentProps['history'], login: any}) => {
const formik = useFormik({
initialValues: {
    email: '',
    password: '',
},
validationSchema: loginSchema,
    onSubmit: (values: LoginFormData) => {
        console.log("before loginuserwithemail");
        loginUserWithEmail(values, history);
        console.log("after")
    },
    });
...
}
```

authActions.ts

```
export const loginUserWithEmail = (formData: LoginFormData, history: RouteComponentProps['history']) => async (dispatch: any, getState: any) => {
  console.log("inside loginuserwithemail function")
  dispatch({ type: LOGIN_WITH_EMAIL_LOADING });
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('/auth/login', formData);
    console.log("inside here")
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_WITH_EMAIL_SUCCESS,
      payload: { token: response.data.token, me: response.data.me },
    });

    dispatch(loadMe());
    history.push('/');
  } catch (err: any) {
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_WITH_EMAIL_FAIL,
      payload: { error: err.response.data.message },
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: convert the onSubmit function into an async function and you would be good to go.  onSubmit:async (values: LoginFormData) => {
        console.log("before loginuserwithemail");
await        loginUserWithEmail(values, history);
        console.log("after")
    },

Comment: @decoder adding the async doesn't seem to work. There's a small warning when I hover my mouse over the "await" which says : 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.

Comment: Do you have errors in your loginSchema? Formik wont submit if there are errors, possibly null values in data etc

Comment: @lockednlevered nope, there's not errors in the loginSchema, the login schema is just the username and password for my form, which I feel before clicking the login button which should be triggering the onSubmit().

Comment: Have you tried just copying the `loginUserWithEmail ` function to the login.tsx file and see if that works? If it does there is an issue with the ES modules.

Comment: @StackUndefined yup, I have. Still not able to hit the function. I'm guessing it has to do with async stuff with the way the function is written.

Answer (score 0):

loginUserWithEmail is hoc (function that returns function)
You need it to call function returned by this function

```
await loginUserWithEmail(values, history)(dispatch, getState);
```

Comment: I tried that but I get this error, even though there is a await in the front.: 

This expression is not callable.
  Type 'Promise<(dispatch: any, getState: any) => Promise<void>>' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
login.tsx(94, 15): Did you forget to use 'await'?